# Rails when does flash get set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following view code, if the user does not click the button 'ADD WO Attachment' - let's say they hit cancel instead.  Should the  `flash[:workorder_id]` be nil?

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tabs-8">
  <%= render 'filtered7' %>
  <% if @workorder.not_closed? %>
      <%= link_to 'ADD WO Attachment', new_attachment_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary', :onclick => flash[:workorder_id] = @workorder.id %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I believe it gets set even if they don't click on the button. And that seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` attribute needs to contain JavaScript that is executed by the client. If you need to set a flash message, you need to make a request, which this is not doing.

This will have the effect of adding `onclick="1"` to your HTML if `@workorder.id` is 1, but it will also set `flash` regardless of being clicked because of how you're forcing an assignment.

If you need to set the `flash` conditionally, you need to make that assignment in whatever handles `new_attachment_path`, presumably the `new` method of `AttachmentsController`.

Answer (score 0):

onclick is expecting javascript code that will be run when you click your link.

You would need to set the flash in the backend and it would be displayed when the page is refreshed. You could do a remote call to your action which sets the flash and renders javascript that updates where the flash is display.